Asian Strike vs Asian Rate option: difference in value
I wrote a few lines of python code to price Asian options. I simulated asset prices with Euler method and run a Monte Carlo to calculate the expected payoffs. I use arithmetic average, discrete sampling.
When pricing ATM options, the Asian Strike price is always higher than the Asian Rate price.
My reasoning would be that in the case of the Asian Strike, the volatility of the underlying asset would remain in full (though the strike is uncertain), whereas in the case of the Asian Rate the volatility of the underlying asset is smoothened by taking the average of S.
I can't quite get my head around it, as I found online resources saying that it should be the opposite. Any help would be really appreciated.

If I've understood your terms correctly, Asian strike has payoff $(S(T) - A(T))^+$, and Asian rate has payoff $(A(T) - K)^+$ In general, intuitively expect the Asian Strike to be lower, as the "negative part" of the payoff is positively correlated to the "positive part", although this probably doesn't fully explain it. Could the issue be with determining what ATM really means? $K = E^Q(S(T))$, $K = S(t)$, $K = E^Q(A(T))$ are all reasonable guesses that could possibly lead to different answers

Rylan, thanks for your comment. You understood the terms correctly. Your explanation makes sense, I will try to play with inputs and see what I get.
